# What is best practice to handle div over div. (Also Responsive)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I'm using bootstrap 4 and I would want to achieve this layout for my website. I have the idea that we can use carousel since its a slider. When I click on the next or previous button, both the yellow slider and the image on the right changes. I also need the slider arrows to be on that position.

Although, I can achieve this through CSS position property for example.

```
position: absolute;
top: some value 
left: some value
.....
```

which will be under the position relative. But I want to achieve this a bootstrap way with some custom CSS so that the responsiveness of this layout won't break. 
What would be the best practice and approach to have such UI keeping in mind it should be responsive too.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: So use a percentage? Or position your arrows relative to the box above it with a container?

Comment: I have the idea about what you are saying, but how would I make it responsive. the @media queries?